# How to fix mysql SELECT query from always stopping at a specific record?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to make a php tool that will get the users registered between specific dates.  However, I'm running into a strange issue.  The query doesn't seem to recognize all of the records in the table.  Let me explain.

Here's the php code:

```
    function getRegistrations($startDate,$endDate) {
    //echo $startDate;
    //echo $endDate;
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$startDate);
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$endDate);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM database.user WHERE created_date>='".$startDate."' AND created_date<='".$endDate."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    $data['query'] = $query;
    $data['content'] = array();
    if($result) {
        $data['status'] = 1;
        $data['message'] = "Success";
    }
    $count = 0;
    $data['num_rows'] = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data['content'][$row['user_id']] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    $data['count'] = $count;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

When I run the query in the mysql workbench, it works just fine.  However, when I'm running it through php, it seems to ignore every record after a certain one.  I can see all the records up to user_id=243, and then it ends.  num_rows and count are still equal, and they're equal to the length of content.  However, if I run the query directly from the mysql workbench, I can see that it should be much higher.
Also, it's always stopping at the same record, regardless of the dates.  If I choose an early start date, then it might return 50 records, but it still stops at the same one.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Although I'm pretty new to MySQL, I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the count not go up either? ANd have you echo'ed your query just to make sure it's the same in your workbench?

Comment: Is user_id a primary key? If you get multiple records with the same user_id, at some point you're just going to be overwriting previous records with the new row.

Comment: Whoops, turns it it was a big mistake.  The php was using the localhost testing database, while I was looking at the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

delete that one particular row. simple as that. reinsert it and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` says query string should not end with a semicolon. Your query should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database.user WHERE created_date>='".$startDate."' AND created_date<='".$endDate."'";
```